# Schema.org hidden html

Tags: html, magento, magento-1.4, php, schema.org

I have contacted google about my rich snippets, and they say that some html is hidden and thats why the rich snippets are not visible yet on the search engine:

Example:
URL: http://www.theprinterdepo.com/hp-color-laser-4700dn-printer-q7493a-r
Markup Type: Product, Reviews
Hidden content: 6

The thing is, I implemented the code this way in magento, summary.phtml, and I dont see how its hidden.

```
<?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
          <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <div class="rating-box">

                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"><meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary()/10 ?>"/></div>
                <span itemprop="reviewCount"><?php echo $this->getReviewsCount() ?></span>
            </div>
          </span>
        <?php endif;?>
        <p class="rating-links">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></a>
            <!--<span class="separator">|</span>-->
            <!--<a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Add Your Review') ?></a>-->
        </p>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($this->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>
    <p class="no-rating"><a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HIDDEN MARKUPS on Rich snippets SCHEMA.ORG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017400/hidden-markups-on-rich-snippets-schema-org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don’t quote the information you got from Google, I can only make some general notes:

Google seems to notice Schema.org conformant markup on major commercial and community sites only. They don’t seem to pay much attention to it otherwise.

Your code has essential syntax errors, like an attempt to put a `div` element inside a `span` element. (The page has a total of 110 reportable markup errors according to validator.w3.org.)

The PHP code is as such irrelevant. Browsers don’t see it, and search engines don’t see it.